# My external css file will not load in electron app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

first-time asker here. I just started making a desktop application with electron js, and when I try to load my external stylesheet into my index.html file, it will not work. Here is my HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bundle</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style.css"
  href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlessioToniolo/Bundle/master/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="header-separation">Hello</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
  /* const electron = require('electron');
  const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
  ipcRenderer.send('item:add', item);
  */
  // For other window:
  /* previous code plus
  ipcRenderer.on('item:add', (e, item) => {
  })
  */
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I tried to link to my external stylesheet originally I just used a path instead of a URL but then when it didn't work I tried loading another stylesheet from a CSS framework which did work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think GitHub allowed that its because the [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), you should host your CSS on other place like unpkg.com.

Here are GitHub CSP. You can look at your network tab on dev tools

```
default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
```

I think it is because used sandbox `sandbox` described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox)

and the content type of the request made was `text/plain` not `text/css` so it is not executed.

I just tried it out and I can't. First you had typo `seperation` on you gits, 2 it should be `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type="style.css" to type="text/css".